# Mocha Test connectivity to DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mocha.js

I would like to test the connectivity to my DB using Mocha, but it seems that I do it the wrong way since whatever the credentials are, the test always passes.

Here is the code I use:

```
describe('Access to DB', function(){
   describe('#fail', function(){
        it('should return -1 because wrong credentials', function(){
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'right host',
                user: 'wrong user',
                password: 'wrong password',
                database: 'right database'
            });
            connection.connect(function(err){
                assert.equal(7,err.stack.indexOf("ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR"));
            });
        });
    })
});
```

I tested the code and when the connection actually fails, it throws an error. Within this error, I get the `indexOf(ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR)` which is equal to 7.

Knowing this, why is my test always passing and how can I correct it to fit my need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to advise mocha that the test you're writing is async. Add a done callback to your `it` function call and call this done callback from connection.connect. The done callback is clever enough to figure out if an error was passed as first argument and in case an error is passed the test will fail.

```
describe('Access to DB', function(){
   describe('#fail', function(){
        it('should return -1 because wrong credentials', function(done){
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'right host',
                user: 'wrong user',
                password: 'wrong password',
                database: 'right database'
            });
            connection.connect(done);
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: "var connection = mysql.createConnection"....... for mysql what package I need to import?

Answer (score -1):

You need to install MySQL.

Use:

```bash
npm install mysql
```

And then, import it like this:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
```